# Android HiddenSSID

Tags: android, xamarin, wifi

I got a question regarding Android WiFi.

I have a code that can connect to a WiFi using SSID and Password. However, in order to have it connect to SSID that's hidden (not broadcasting), I figured out that I need to set **HiddenSSID = true**.

I also tested **HiddenSSID = true** will connect to "Non-Hidden SSID" with the name SSID that's being broadcasted.

**My question is, if HideenSSID = true give me the ability to connect to both Hidden and Non-Hidden SSID, why should I ever not set HiddenSSID=true?**

Anyone can help me understand what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I find [hiddenSSID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiConfiguration#hiddenSSID) here. It's a property of `WifiConfiguration`.

The description says:

> `public boolean hiddenSSID`
>
> This is a network that does not broadcast its SSID, so an
>   SSID-specific probe request must be used for scans.

So, in my understanding, `hiddenSSID` is a value that determine whether the `SSID` of `WiFi` is visiable in the `WiFi` list.

Back to your question:

> if HideenSSID = true give me the ability to connect to both Hidden
>   and Non-Hidden SSID, why should I ever not set HiddenSSID=true?

Through the document, I don't think set `HideenSSID` true or false will affect the ability to connect both Hidden and Non-Hidden SSID.

It's my personal understanding, correct me if I'm wrong.

Refer: [WifiConfiguration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager#updateNetwork(android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration))

Comment: Thank you for the information. In order to connect to hidden network, you must set the hiddenSSID to true. Without this setting set to true, it will not connect to a hidden network.